# AJAX form not submitting data to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am not sure where the steps go wrong in here since everything goes as it should with the exception of the serialized data not being submitted into the database.

I know the connection to the DB works. I use it in other pages that are pulling data from the DB. I just can't seem to be able to INSERT.

Step 1: Fill out form

Step 2: Data from form is validated. **Disclaimer**: *I fully intend to put in full security checks and trim to avoid SQL injections. Simply working on function first.*

Step 3: Serialized data passed to usersubmit.php for DB insertion.

Any help is very appreciated.

register.php

```
<script src="js/click.js"></script>

<form action="js/click.js" method="post">

  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text"id="first_name" name="first_name" /><br>

  <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" /><br>

  <label for="username" >Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br>

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br><br>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" /><br><br><br>

  <button type="submit" id="reg-submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

click.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#reg-submit').click(function() {
        var firstName = $('#first_name').val();
        var lastName = $('#last_name').val();
        var userName = $('#username').val();
        var userPass = $('#password').val();
        var userEmail = $('#email').val();
        if (firstName =='' || lastName =='' || userName =='' || userPass =='' || userEmail =='') {  
          alert ('Nope');
        } 
         else
        {
        var formData = $("form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "usersubmit.php",
              data: formData,
              cache: false,
              success: function(){
                $('#main-content').load('next-page.php').hide().fadeIn('slow');
              }
            });
        };
        return false;
    });
});
```

usersubmit.php

```
<?php include 'users_db.php'; ?>

<?php

   $first1=$_POST['first_name'];
   $last1=$_POST['last_name'];
   $username1=$_POST['username'];
   $pass1=$_POST['password'];
   $email01=$_POST['email']; 

   $userinfo = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registered_users (FirstName, LastName, Username, Password, Email) VALUES (:first, :last, :user, :pass, :email)");
   $userinfo->bindParam(':first', $first1);
   $userinfo->bindParam(':last', $last1);
   $userinfo->bindParam(':user', $username1);
   $userinfo->bindParam(':pass', $pass1);
   $userinfo->bindParam(':email', $email01);

   $userinfo->execute();

   $userinfo->close();

   $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: what does ajax response?

Comment: upon success, it loads the next page into the main-content div within the index.php (currently functioning properly)

Comment: Form action to a js file? Isn't it suspicious error check.

Comment: Why don't you return the contents of the page in your success and see if there are any errors?

Comment: At least add a small trace like `echo 'it runs';` to see if you get it back in JS.

Comment: i think you dont need action in form since you are passing value from html to ajax to server side php. just like what Jai is saying :)

Comment: You should move bindparamz above insert I guess.

Comment: Your main problem comes from the fact that you do no validation or error checking, or otherwise it would be much more obvious around where the problem actually occurs.  Right now you're not even checking if your DB calls give errors.  I don't see a connection either, hoping it's in your include.

Comment: _"serialized data not being submitted into the database."_ have you checked to see if the sql query ran successfully? I dont see any error handling after you call execute

Comment: @Jai:  No, that part is actually fine.

Comment: @juliepelletier then I guess your previous comment should be the ideal way to forward. OP should see that comment.

Comment: Will work on the error handling. Seems to be the #1 takeaway here. Will serve me best in the long run I am sure. Thanks all.

Comment: Are you using a wrapper class/library for your db calls? If not its supposed to be bind_param not bindParam, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @KyleHeier On a side note, if you switch your check for empty, you will help yourself if you make it less manual: `$(this).on('submit','form',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var fData = $(this).find('input'); var isEmpty = false; $.each(fData,function(k,v){ if($(v).val() == '') { isEmpty = true; return false; } }); if (isEmpty) { alert ('Nope'); } else...etc`. See if this works a bit better.